# Spring mvc schema giving errors

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a **spring-mvc project**

It consists of following files

**1)applicationContext.xml**

**2)web-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

Both the files consists of **xsi:schemaLocation**

Sometimes in the project it will give error on the **xsi:schemaLocation**

but after **updating 3-4 times** the error will be gone.

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">



    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <import resource="mongodb-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

My webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

Is this the right solution that I need to update the project to remove the errors?

I am using eclipse-oxygen and doing maven update

Comment: you can add your xml file  content here ...  to have a look

Answer (score 0):

I have a spring mvc project setup in intellij idea. Please see the following schema location in my web-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

You said that the error disappears when you update the code. You tried to update from version control? Please clarify on this.

Comment: I tried to do maven-update in eclipse oxygen and the errors are gone